# do while in do while in php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, do-while

That loop using do while, and it is working fine but when I add another do while in to this the second do while work but first do while only show one row not all 10 row. My code is below

```
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['date']; ?></td>
<?php do { ?>
  <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['nav']; ?></td>
  <?php } while ($row_Recordset1= mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

My date should be displayed once in a row but all the other td will be took from nav;

This is what I want:

```
   ------------------------
   |2014-02-26|5.5|3.2|3.5|
   ------------------------
   |2014-02-25|3.1|1.2|1.5|
```

But I'm currently getting:

```
------------------------
|2014-02-26|5.5|3.2|3.5|
------------------------
```

Comment: why not just have one `do`/`while` and have the `do` do two echos? Because each time you call the `fetch_assoc` it `moves the internal data pointer ahead.`

Comment: why aren't you using just `while()` without the `do`?

Comment: I can see that you are probably new to the community. First I want to say "Welcome to the StackOverflow community!". Second, I would like to ask you to remember to upvote answers you like and click the checkmark for the answer you choose as the best (it doesn't have to be my answer). Thanks and enjoy the site! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc

It moves the internal pointer one step ahead, so each time you do mysql_fetch_assoc() you get the next value, hence only your enternal do while is executed. That is, only date from the first row is output, and all other values are output in second do while;

Try this for exercise:

```
$q = mysql_query("SOME MYSQL QUERY WITH MINIMUM THREE ROWS");
$f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$f = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);

print_r($f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
<?php do { ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row_Recordset1['nav']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1)); ?>
```

Because each time you use [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) it does the following

> Returns an associative array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the internal data pointer ahead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, *please* don't bounce in and out of PHP like that...

```
<?php 
do { 
  echo '<tr>
  <td>';
  echo $row_Recordset1['date']; 
  echo '</td>';
  do { 
    echo '<td>';
    echo $row_Recordset1['nav']; 
    echo '</td>';
  } while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
  echo '</tr>';
} while ($row_Recordset1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset1));
?>
```

Where do you fetch your first $row_Recordset1? Somewhere earlier than this code? You're going to output table cells (`<td>`) until you run out of rows. I don't think you want that.

Answer (score -1):

Part of the reason this doesn't work is because you are re-assigning the value of the same variable. If you don't want to lose it then you cannot do it this way. At the very least it is a bad idea if you ever intend to do anything new with the code.

Next, I really recommend you populate an array with the data first before you ever do anything with outputting it. It is a very good idea to separate logic from output.

Your code should look more like this:

```
<?php
//Assumes you have already connected to a mysqli resource
$conditional_data_filtered = $mysqli->real_escape_string($conditional_data);
$sql = "SELECT date, nav FROM some_table WHERE some_column = '" . $conditional_data_filtered . "'";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data = array(); //Make sure we start with a fresh array each time.
        $data['date'] = $row['date'];

        //Now I think you have a bunch of data in the nav you need to loop through
        $nav_filtered = $mysqli->real_escape_string($row['nav']);
        $subSql = "SELECT some_data FROM navigation WHERE some_identifier = '" . $nav_filtered . "'";

        if ($subResult = $mysqli->query($subSql)) {
            while ($subRow = $subResult->fetch_assoc()) {
                $data['nav'][] = $subRow;
            }
        }

        $rowList[] = $data;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

foreach ($rowList as $rowData) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $rowData['date'] . "</td>";

    foreach ($rowData['nav'] as $navData) {
        echo "<td>" . $navData['some_info'] . "</td>";
    }

    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

***Just a note:** If you really don't have sub-data and just want to output the next column then you don't need a sub-loop. You just need to echo the contents of the column like you did with the first one. Then you can get rid of the sub-loops I have shown above and just put it within the first loop.*

Comment: Nice SQL injection there. mysql_* extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, please use mysqli_, or use PDO (which also allows you to use prepared statements, which prevent SQL injections). http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: Good point, I have gotten so used to using frameworks that handle all that for me and hand me objects that I had forgotten about that. Luckily for this example few people are upgraded all the way to 5.5 thus far. I will fix my code though. That and make sure it is escaped properly.

Comment: At the very least you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string`, annoying as it is. Better to just express it in PDO notation as an incentive to ditch the horribly out of date `mysql_query` function.

Comment: Yeah, got that corrected as I said I was working on. (Other distractions came up that slowed me down).